# How to change default User-agent in mediaplayer of the android

Tags: android, user-agent, media-player

In which file of the android repo do i have to change the default user-agent?
I need to set this string as default user-agent for the media-player:
**HTC Streaming Player vodafone_uk / 1.0 / htc_bravo / 2.2**

Answer (score 2):

```
public void setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri, Map<String, String> headers);
```

In you app which controls MediaPlayer instance, pass the user agent in the header map as follows:

```
Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();;
headerMap.put("User-Agent", "my user agent value");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri, headerMap);
```